# Algebraic help needed for Horners Law, displaying wrong answer c++

Tags: c++

I am expecting to enter in the binary number 11001101 one char at a time followed by an ! and convert it to its decimal number. I multiply it by 2 and add it to the previous term to give a result total I called decimal_num.

I display the output as I run through my while loop and the numbers change from what I expect to 98. I do not know enough about the language to debug as this is only my second attempt to write in it and any information would be helpful.

```
int main() {

int base, decimal_num = 0;

char numberEnterInBase;

//Ask user for a base number:
cout << "Enter a base number from 2 and 10: " << endl << endl;

//Store input as base & check for correct input:
cin >> base;
while (base < 2 || base > 10) {
    cout << "Please enter a number from 2 to 10." << endl;
    cin >> base;
}

//Ask for a entry for number in base and store:
cout << "Please enter a number in that base terminated by !: " << endl;
cin >> numberEnterInBase;

//Subtract ASCII code for '0':
numberEnterInBase - '0';

//While loop to apply rules of Horners Law:
while (numberEnterInBase != '!') {

    //Displays the numbers every pass through the loop to debug:
    cout << "Numbers: Total: " << decimal_num << " , Char cin: " << numberEnterInBase << " , Base: " << base << endl;

    /*
    Taking char entered in and multiplying by base.
    Then adds to total(decimal_num):
    */
    decimal_num += numberEnterInBase * base;

    //Displays the total after multiplying to help debug:
    cout << decimal_num << endl << endl;

    //Moves to next cin entry:
    cin >> numberEnterInBase;
}

return 0;
 }
```

> -----OUTPUT-----

```
Enter a base number from 2 and 10:

2

Please enter a number in that base terminated by !:

1100101!

Numbers: Total: 0 , Char cin: 1 , Base: 2
98

Numbers: Total: 98 , Char cin: 1 , Base: 2
196

Numbers: Total: 196 , Char cin: 0 , Base: 2
292

Numbers: Total: 292 , Char cin: 0 , Base: 2
388

Numbers: Total: 388 , Char cin: 1 , Base: 2
486

Numbers: Total: 486 , Char cin: 0 , Base: 2
582

Numbers: Total: 582 , Char cin: 1 , Base: 2
680

Press any key to continue . . .
```

> ----EXPECTING----

```
I'm wanting 11001101  to equal 205.

Horner's Scheme:

((((((((1*2 + 1)2 + 0)2 + 0)2 + 1)2 + 1)2 + 0)2 + 1

1*2=2+1=3*2=6+0=6*2=12+0=12*2=24+1=25*2=50+1=51*2=102+0=102*2=204+1=205

11001101 (binary) = 205 (decimal)
```

Comment: `numberEnterInBase - '0'` does nothing. You probably wanted to use `-=`. Also, you do this in the wrong place.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be at *each* iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> numberEnterInBase - '0';
> ```

This is an expression. It evaluates what you get when subtracting the ASCII code for `0` from `numberEnterInBase`, but then nothing is done with that evaluation. It disappears into the ether as if it never existed.

What you presumably intended to do was replace the value in `numberEnterInBase` with the result of the evaluation. This can be done one of two ways.

Option 1:

```
 numberEnterInBase = numberEnterInBase - '0';
```

Option 2 (more succinct):

```
 numberEnterInBase -= '0';
```

You'll also want to repeat this operation each time you get a new value for `numberEnterInBase`.

Note that fixing your logic will mess up your debug output since `numberEnterInBase` will now contain a control character (a.k.a. an "unprintable" character). You can rectify that by casting to an integer when you stream it, for example (and not a complete example):

```
cout << static_cast<int>(numberEnterInBase);
```

Also, for future reference: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). (It should be useful since there is still another bug in your program.)